# How to add a event to a function from parent class without changing the previous code

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, class, object, pyqt4

I am making a GUI in Pyqt4
I have a main.py file which has a structre like this:

Main.py

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):


def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(1291, 893)

    self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.newDealer)
    self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
    self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777212, 16777215))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
```

and I have another file test.py which has structure like this

test.py

```
from main import *

class myclass(Ui_MainWindow):
    def foo(self):
       print("Hello")

    def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
       pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.foo)    #I want to find correction here
```

When I Execute test.py .I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
File "test.py", line 15, in setupUi
pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.foo)
NameError: name 'pushButton_3' is not defined
```

Can Anyone help please??

Comment: I tried with self too but error was   File "test.py", line 14, in setupUi
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.foo)
AttributeError: 'myclass' object has no attribute 'pushButton_3'

Comment: Please read the [PyQt4 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) on how to use the ui files created by pyuic. The third example shown there is probably what you want - but obviously you need to use a `QMainWindow`, rather than a `QDialog`.